# How can one reference subdomains on a dev server that also correctly resolve on a production server?

Tags: apache, subdomain, production, dev-to-production

I've got a LAMP dev server at something like dev.example.com. Eventually this will be replicated to something like www.example.com where we will have root access.

I'd like to have the sys admin set up a few subdomains (e.g., subdomain1.example.com) such that they will work on both the dev server and the production server without the references to those subdomains having to be rewritten.

Can Apache be configured on the dev and production servers such that my code can reference something like subdomain1.localhost? Is there some other way of doing this?

(The servers will run recent versions of CentOS and the AMP stack.)

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you are happy to return a different answer (subdomain1.LOCALHOST vs subdomain1.example..com), that is you are happy change/parameterize your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. By parameterizing the code I assume you mean having the subdomain reference be dynamically generated based on what server it's on. Is that correct? If so, I suppose that might work. However, the context is that content admins (non-developers) will need to be inputting some of those subdomain references into a CMS (Drupal). It would be far preferable to not have to teach them to input PHP.

Comment: You can't have relative URLs to a different subdomain. Something will need to translate them or switch between the outputs. Maybe a custom input filter on the dev site that translates "live" URLs to the dev one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the CDN module. As the name implies, this is intended to be used with content delivery networks but essentially all it does is a rule-based re-writing of the URLs that Drupal outputs. I've used it to re-write URLs so that different file types can be served from unique hostnames (again, to maximize parallel downloads).

Answer (score 0):

reading your question again, I think that you want your code to always return subdomain1.localhost, and you want apache to somehow change this to subdomain1.example.com on your production server.

You could do this with ProxyPassReverse, although you might have to run two copies of Apache if the subdomain1 is on the same machine. (I don't know if Apache will cope with talking to itself here).  This is an expensive solution.

Instead, I recommend your parameterize your code.
On rails stacks, the easiest way to do this with the production.rb cp that capistrano recommends, and you might want to investigate similar ways of deploying your PHP code.